# Valiant Boiler - 3 months old

Tags: heating, gas, water-pressure, boiler, combi

In September I had a Valiant boiler fitted in my 2 bedroom house. It hasn’t worked properly ever since. Every time I put the heating on my pressure drops from 1.5 to 0.3 bars and I get the spanner showing and the heating turns off and I have to add more water to bring bar level back up. I’ve bled my radiators and as far as I know haven’t got any leaks in my radiators as have wood flooring  throughout so my floor would lift wouldn’t it if it was getting wet from a leak, albeit large or small.   My heating engineer can’t find the problem. Does anyone have any ideas. I am due to rent my property next year and need to get sorted before I
do. Valiant have said their boiler is not at fault.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What pressure drops? "Spanner"? Do you really have to keep adding water again and again? Why isn't the person who installed it helping you?

Comment: Hi there sorry my screen disappeared so had to re-log in. I live in the UK - it’s the pressure gauge in my boiler that seems to control the heating and hot water, sorry I don’t really understand how it works. Sometimes it goes a couple of days and it’s fine then all of a sudden the pressure drops and I get a spanner sign to say I need an engineer but when my engineer fitted my boiler he explained how it worked.  The pressure doesn’t appear to drop when just using hot water but just heating. My engineer is trying to solve problem but think he’s at a loss of what it might be.